# Using Reference VS getReference multiple calls to the same object

Tags: java

Simply I want to ask which is better of the following cases:

```
import com.x.x.x.Document;
.
.
Document doc=user.getDoc();
MyFile file=Converter.getFile(doc.getFile());
MyTheme theme=Converter.getTheme(doc.getTheme());
```

OR

```
MyFile file=Converter.getFile(user.getDoc().getFile());
MyTheme theme=Converter.getTheme(user.getDoc().getTheme());
```

Since first case requires importing `Document` second doesn't and at the same time second requires multiple calls to `getDoc()` first doesn't so which is better Readability & functionality

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first style, with a local `doc`, is superior, mostly for its readability: the readers of your code will not have to guess (or read the documentation) if `getDoc()` returns the same instance on multiple calls, and be sure that you are making the calls on exactly the same instance.

The performance may or may not be an issue, depending on the implementation of `getDoc()`. The first usage style (with the `doc`) will be at least as fast as the second one, though.

Answer (score 1):

> Since first case requires importing Document second don't

Not sure what you mean: in both examples you need a reference to your document. The two examples are identical functionally and performance-wise (assuming `getDoc` is simply a getter).

I would however use the first version for two reasons:

- I find it more readable than successive method calls
- if your user is `null`,  you will get a NPE on line `Document doc = user.getDoc();` so it will be obvious (in the second example, if you get a NPE on `MyFile file = Converter.getFile(user.getDoc().getFile());`, it could either be the user or the document that is null).

Comment: Actually It doesn't require an Import,Since **Document** is already imported in **User** class

Comment: @YouYou Oh you meant an actual `import` statement? I would not care too much about that either...